# After docker compose localhost:8000 not open page in browser

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, docker, npm

Hello i'm newbie in docker. I have project on laravel 9 with node version 12.14.0,PostgreSql 10,PHP 8.1.2
This my git repository:https://github.com/Daniil1996-vrn/DEVJuniorPHP/tree/main/DEVJuniorPHP
I create docker file, webserver ngnix conf file (but when i'm creating project i usr artisan server) on this repository:https://github.com/othyn/docker-compose-laravel#running-attached
This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  laravel:

volumes:
  database:

services:
  database:
    image: postgres:10
    container_name: postgres
    restart: "no"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - laravel
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "admin1234"
      POSTGRES_DB: "DEVJuniorPHP"
      
      
    

  composer:
    image: composer:latest
    container_name: composer
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    working_dir: /app
    command: composer install

  node:
    image: node:12
    container_name: node
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    working_dir: /app
    command: npm install

  app:
    container_name: app
    restart: "no"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      
    networks:
      - laravel
    depends_on:
      - composer
      - node
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/app/dockerfile
    
    command: php-fpm

  webserver:
    image: nginx:stable
    container_name: webserver
    restart: "no"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/webserver/nginx.conf/
    networks:
      - laravel
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - database
      - app
```

Docker File:

```
FROM php:8.1.4-fpm-alpine3.14

# Update package manager ready for deps to be installed
RUN apk update



# Set the working directory of the container to the hosted directory
WORKDIR /var/www
```

nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;

        # Uncomment to extend nginx's max timeout to 1 hour
        # fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    }
}
```

When i run command in terminal Visual Studio code docker-compose up -d i next have messagess in terminal:
Starting node     ... done
Starting composer ... done
Starting postgres ...
Starting postgres ... done
Recreating webserver ... done
PS D:\DEVJuniorPHP\DEVJuniorPHP> docker-compose up -d
Starting node     ... done
Starting postgres ...
Starting postgres ... done
app is up-to-date
webserver is up-to-date

But whene i go to page localhost:8000 in browser  i see the message:Can't access site
Please help me resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Error is that the nginx vhost is pointing to the wrong folder.

You didn't map the *nginx.conf* volume into the container volume so it doesn't really find the path to the application.
In the volume part of the *webserver* service, you must put the path of the vhost container:

`- ./docker/webserver/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Get back to me if it's good !

Comment: docker compose up -start succesful when i write this string:
- ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
but when i write in browser:
http://localhost:8000/ or http://192.168.99.100:8000/
192.168.99.100 it's ip docker quick start terminal
but site not opne (message cannot access site)

Comment: instead you have to map the `nginx.conf` file to that of the container